# Building JVM for Scala 2_11

Tags: pact

This is a question about the project https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm.

**Problem**

When I am validating pacts I need to be able to use client side authentication, as the providers actually require client side authentication. I'll prefix what I am saying with a declaration that I am not very familiar with groovy: I mostly program in scala, java or javascript. Having looked at the code I think that client side authentication is not currently supported, so I'd like to make a pull request with that support in it.

**What I've done so far**

I have managed to get Https working with a truststore: I copied the HttpTarget and created a HttpsTarget, and in the HttpsTarget specified the truststore in the providerinfo. Unfortunately looking at the code there doesn't seem to be a way of specifying the client certificate, so I need to change the providerinfo class to be able to specify where it is (in the same way the the truststore is provided).

My problem is that I've got the code compiling using the advice in the 'for contributors', but when I publish locally, I am only publishing for scala version 2_12. Because of version issues and binary incompatibilities between scala versions, I need to publish to scala 2_11. My skills with gradle are even less than my skills with groovy. I've done a search for all the references to scalaVersion, and found that there is quite a lot of logic around it, but I've not managed to track down where it is specified.

**Question**

If I **can** use client side authentication with the current pact validator could you let me know. If not, could you tell me how to publish the project with support for scala 2_11?

Thanks

Comment: if you're using Scala, have you tried using the scala-pact implementation? https://github.com/ITV/scala-pact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I made my own Http Target. My need is to run from Junit, not the general case, and this is good enough:

```
public class HttpsTarget extends HttpTarget {
    public HttpsTarget(final int port) {
        super("https", "localhost", port, "/", false);
    }

    static class HttpsClientFactory implements IHttpClientFactory {

        @NotNull
        @Override
        public CloseableHttpClient newClient(Object o) {
            SSLContext sslContext = // put here code to make ssl context
            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients
                    .custom()
                    .setSSLContext(sslContext)
                    .build();
            return httpClient;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void testInteraction(final String consumerName, final Interaction interaction, PactSource source) {
        ProviderInfo provider = getProviderInfo(source);
        ConsumerInfo consumer = new ConsumerInfo(consumerName);
        ProviderVerifier verifier = setupVerifier(interaction, provider, consumer);

        Map<String, Object> failures = new HashMap<>();
        ProviderClient client = new ProviderClient(provider, new HttpsClientFactory());
        verifier.verifyResponseFromProvider(provider, interaction, interaction.getDescription(), failures, client);
        reportTestResult(failures.isEmpty(), verifier);

        try {
            if (!failures.isEmpty()) {
                verifier.displayFailures(failures);
                throw getAssertionError(failures);
            }
        } finally {
            verifier.finialiseReports();
        }
    }
}
```